# mySQL - Sum value from different rows where two values in different columns match

Tags: mysql, subquery

My MySQL-skills are limited and usually I don't need much more than selecting the columns I need with some conditions from a single table. Now I need more than that, and I'm lost.

What I'm after is to add the quantity of an item where two different columns match, and all data is in the same table.

Example of table;

```
Item    Quantity    Col1    Col2
A       1           123     234
A       3           456     758
A       2           588     258
A       2           234     456
```

My initial thought was to write a query with a condition like following;

```
WHERE Col1 = Col2
```

I couldn't wrap my head around why I didn't recieve any results.. 'till this morning when I realized that the query is only checking for matches within the same row. I realized I needed to write a subquery and now I'm here. Subqueries to me is much like algebra to so many. It starts out well and then I lose myself somewhere down the road. In my head this should be simple, but I feel I'm overcomplicating things.

How would a query need to look like to do this job? I want to learn this because I know I'll be needing it in the future.

*edit

What I want to achieve with the query is to add the quantity of the rows whenever there is a match between Col1 and Col2.

*edit2
Not sure if it gives any hints of what I'm wanting to do but..

```
select Item, sum(Quantity)
from exampleTable
where col1 = 
(select col2
from exampleTable)
```

***edit3 - the solution to my problem**

Beforehand I want to apologize for a poor description of my problem.
Consulted a colleague and solution to my problem was rather simple.

```
select a.Quantity +
(select b.Quantity
from exampleTable b
where Col2 = Col1)
from exampleTable a
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm looking to sum the quantity of the rows whenever there's a match between Col1 and Col2.

Comment: `select count(col1) from mytable where col1 = col2;` ? I assume you mean count when you say "sum the quantity" but it's unclear.

Comment: Was my initial thought as well, but that would only count whenever there's a match between col1 and col2 on the same row. I want to sum the quantity from different rows whenever there's a match between col1 and col2.

Comment: It would help clarify your question if you add expected output to the question. I think what you mean is sum the quantities from all the rows where a value occurs in either col1 or col2 so 456 would = 5 because 456 occurs in row 2 and row 4 , 234 = 3 because it appears in row 1 and row 3.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you clear you want to add (sum) the quantity of the item, whenever the COL1 and Col2 are equal...

Here is the query for it

SELECT sum(QUANTITY) from example where COL1 = Col2

Comment: Well, almost. I want to add the quantity whenever Col1 and Col2 are equal on different rows.

Answer (score 0):

select sum(Quantity) from table_name where col1=col2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this where the sub query sums the quantity unioning both columns and the outer query sums the sum and tests that there was more than 1 occurance

```
Drop table if exists t;
create table t(Item varchar(1) ,  Quantity int,    Col1  int,  Col2 int);
insert into t values
('A'   ,    1       ,    123  ,   234),
('A'   ,    3       ,    456  ,   758),
('A'   ,    2       ,    588  ,   258),
('A'   ,    2       ,    234  ,   456);


select item,sum(sumqty) sumqty,sum(obs) sumcount, col
from
(
select item, sum(quantity) sumqty, count(*) as obs, col1 as col
from t 
group by item, col1
union all
select item, sum(quantity),count(*) as obs, col2
from t 
group by item, col2
) s
group by item, col having sum(obs) > 1;

+------+--------+----------+------+
| item | sumqty | sumcount | col  |
+------+--------+----------+------+
| A    |      3 |        2 |  234 |
| A    |      5 |        2 |  456 |
+------+--------+----------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This was not the solution to my problem, BUT(!) it yielded some interesting results and gave me a couple of ideas how to use the data. Thanks!